# How to add XML attributes in XML Serialization C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Hi am having some problems in XML serialization of XML attributes, following are some details of class file generated from XSD.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/UpdatePolicy.xsd")]
public partial class policyClasses {

    private policyClassesClass[] classField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("class")]
    public policyClassesClass[] @class {
        get {
            return this.classField;
        }
        set {
            this.classField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/UpdatePolicy.xsd")]
public partial class policyClassesClass {

    private string company_idField;

    private string deductable_rateField;

    private string max_limitField;

    private string class_nameField;

    private string class_numberField;

    private policyClassesClassCchi_class_number cchi_class_numberField;

    private policyClassesClassAction_type action_typeField;

    private bool action_typeFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string company_id {
        get {
            return this.company_idField;
        }
        set {
            this.company_idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="positiveInteger")]
    public string deductable_rate {
        get {
            return this.deductable_rateField;
        }
        set {
            this.deductable_rateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="positiveInteger")]
    public string max_limit {
        get {
            return this.max_limitField;
        }
        set {
            this.max_limitField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string class_name {
        get {
            return this.class_nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.class_nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string class_number {
        get {
            return this.class_numberField;
        }
        set {
            this.class_numberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public policyClassesClassCchi_class_number cchi_class_number {
        get {
            return this.cchi_class_numberField;
        }
        set {
            this.cchi_class_numberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public policyClassesClassAction_type action_type {
        get {
            return this.action_typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.action_typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool action_typeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.action_typeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.action_typeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/UpdatePolicy.xsd")]
public enum policyClassesClassCchi_class_number {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("4")]
    Item4,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/UpdatePolicy.xsd")]
public enum policyClassesClassAction_type {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("10")]
    Item10,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,
```

I managed to generate XML based on this class by serialization, but not having any idea to add the XML attribute to the XML generated, i supposed to get an output as below.

```
 <classes>
<class action_type="10">
  <company_id>999</company_id>
  <deductable_rate>20</deductable_rate>
  <max_limit>800</max_limit>
  <class_name>Class A</class_name>
  <class_number>1</class_number>
  <cchi_class_number>2</cchi_class_number>
</class>
```

how to add the attribute to the element `<class action_type = "10">`
from `/// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public policyClassesClassAction_type action_type {
            get {
                return this.action_typeField;
            }
            set {
                this.action_typeField = value;
            }
        }`

Please somebody help me on this to manage my deadlines, also tell me if anything is not clear for the valuable responses
Joe

Comment: If you're not getting the 'action_type' attribute value then it might be null

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the generated class is marked `partial`.
Add another class right next to the generated one in your project and give it a similar name, such as *GeneratedClasses*.addon.cs. Add this in your new file:

```
public partial class policyClasses {
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
  public policyClassesClassAction_type action_type { get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanx Sten let me try like u suggested.

Comment: Sten thanks for your help, actually i figured it out why this was not showing as attribute. 

public bool action_typeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.action_typeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.action_typeFieldSpecified = value;
        }

before using action_type i need to specify the action_typeSpecified is true or false.